# How to call a function right before object is called

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a function at the second an object is being called?

I have following object:

```
var z;
var a = {
    b: function(){
      return z * 2;
     }
    c: function(){
      return z * 3;
     }
    d: function(){
      return z * 4;
     },
    e: function(){
      return z * 5;
     }
}

var onObjectInvoke = function(){
  z = (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

I want to reset the value of `z` before `a.d()` is being called, here's the flow I mean, when `a.d()` is called:

1. call `onObjectInvoke`.
2. call `a.d()`;

I'm looking for some kind of constructor, is there any way?

Comment: I think you may be looking for Proxy.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Why don't you use ES6 class constructors and invoke getter methods?

Comment: Why don't you call that function from inside the `d` method? BTW: objects are not called -- functions are.

Comment: I have a very large object that contains tens of functions, I don't want to call the function per nested function, moreover I treat my functions as nested objects that's why I consider them as object, so it's obvious for me that functions are called.

Comment: In your question you say `I want to reset the value of z before a.d() is being called,`  in your comments to the answers you write `I don't want to repeat calling onObjectInvoke() for every single inner function` so if `z` should not be reset before every call of `d()` then at which call of `d()` should it be reset?

Comment: I mean I want to create sort of constructor or prototype, so I write `onObjectInvoke()` once but it is invoked for every children of object `a` when say `a.d()`, or `a.e()` is called.

Comment: You will probably need to add more code if you want better answers. As it is now, the answers you have gotten fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just call `onObjectInvoke()` before calling `a.d()`? Your life will be a lot easier if you allow your functions to be stateless and operate on given parameters rather than using a global `z` variable.

```
var z;
var a = {
    d: function(x){
        return x * 4;
    }
}

var onObjectInvoke = function(){
  return (new Date()).getTime();
}

z = a.d(onObjectInvoke());
```

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear why I can't repeat calling `onObjectInvoke()` for every single inner function.

Comment: This doesn't call onObjectInvoke for every function. If you don't want to update z, pass z as-is. If you do, pass onObjectInvoke() as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var z;
var a = {
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: function(){
        onObjectInvoke();
        return z * 4;
    }
}

var onObjectInvoke = function() {
    z = (new Date()).getTime();
}

console.log(a.d());
```

Comment: I don't want to repeat calling onObjectInvoke() for every single inner function

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to add one more layer and then access `onObjectInvoke()` in that layer first and return the functions from that layer as object and call the desired function on return value

```
  a.defaultFunc().d()
```

```js
var z;
var a = {
  defaultFunc: function() {
    onObjectInvoke()
    return {
      b: function() {
        return z * 2;
      },
      c: function() {
        return z * 3;
      },
      d: function() {
        return z * 4;
      },
      e: function() {
        return z * 5;
      }
    }
  }
}
var onObjectInvoke = function() {
  console.log('reseting z')
  z = (new Date()).getTime();
}

console.log(a.defaultFunc().d())
console.log(a.defaultFunc().e())
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I want to know if there is a tricky way not to call `defaultFunc()` explicitly, that's what a constructor does, in that case the user who is going to work with my codes does not have to know about it.

Comment: @Mohammadlm71 but why you wanna go for tricky ways when you have simple way to do it, you can define one function and call internally on all other function if you don't want to call like `a.defaultFunc().d()` as show in [`t.niese's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025013/9624435),

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you most certainly don't want to use `z` directly but invoke a function that returns the value for you. And in that function, you will either reset `z` or return it depending on your current use case.

Having external code that heavily modifies the behavior/outcome of a function is always a bad idea with regard to maintainability and readability.

```js
var z;
var resetZ = true;

var a = {
  getZ: function() {
    if (resetZ) {
      z = (new Date()).getTime();
    }
    return z;
  },
  b: function() {
    return this.getZ() * 2;
  }
  c: function() {
    return this.getZ() * 3;
  }
  d: function() {
    return this.getZ() * 4;
  },
  e: function() {
    return this.getZ() * 5;
  }
}

a.d()
```

You for sure should not use a global `resetZ`, but as it is not clear how exactly you use your code it is not clear how to structure the code. Or maybe `getZ` should be a free function, instead of a function belonging to the object.